# Comparing two identical tables data by Date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I write a SQL statement to compare current date and date yesterday. Tables have identical columns. I need to check what data is different in which column by the two dates chosen and display the changes between the 2 tables.

Here is the stored procedure I started

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_CompareNetworksandRatings]
       @media_month_id smallint,
       @rating_category_id tinyint,
       @rate_date datetime
  AS
  BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT DISTINCT
       nn.nielsen_network_id,
       nn.code,
       nn.name
  FROM
       daily_ratings dr (NOLOCK)
  JOIN media_months mm (NOLOCK) ON mm.id=dr.media_month_id
        AND mm.id=@media_month_id
  JOIN uvw_nielsen_network_universes nn (NOLOCK) ON nn.nielsen_network_id=dr.nielsen_network_id
        AND nn.start_date<=mm.start_date AND (nn.end_date>=mm.start_date OR nn.end_date IS NULL) 
  WHERE
      dr.rating_category_id=@rating_category_id
      AND dr.media_month_id=@media_month_id
      AND dr.rating_date=@rate_date
  ORDER BY
      nn.code
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a case construct for every column you want to check.  Something like this:

```
 select case when t2.f1 <> t1.f1 then 'yes' else 'no' end f1_changed
```